# error executing child request for server.transfer with Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

I have created the handler to process .html pages in my asp.net c# web application.
I also use url rewriting concepts.
Handler works fine when any html requrest come to server/website.
Coding details are as follows:

web.config Handler Code:

```
<add verb="*" path="*.html," validate="false" type="MyProject.ContentHandler,MyProject" />
```

ContentHandler.cs Code:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
            string strMapPage = string.Empty;
            if (context.Request.Url.ToString().Contains("category"))
            {
                strMapPage = "/Links.aspx?ID=" + ProducID;
            }
            else
            {
                strMapPage = context.Request.Url.ToString();
            }
            context.Server.Transfer(strMapPage);
}
```

This method works fine for any .html request like for this page   http://localhost:9111/user-category-1.html
But when i try to open the page like '/JS/TinyMCE/imagemanager/index.html'
It throws the error "Error executing child request for /JS/TinyMCE/imagemanager/index.html"

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the handler in web.config and it resolved the issue.

```
<add name="tinyMceIndexHandler" verb="*" path="/js/tiny_mce/plugins/imagemanager/pages/im/index.html" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
```

Answer (score 0):

From microsoft:

Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) dispatches the Server.Transfer or the Server.Execute request to the appropriate Internet Server Application Programming Interface (ISAPI) extension based on the extension of the requesting file. For example, a request for an .aspx page is dispatched to the Aspnet_isapi.dll ISAPI extension.

After the request is dispatched to appropriate ISAPI extension, the ISAPI extension cannot call another ISAPI extension. You receive the error message "Error executing child request for PageName.asp" because the Aspnet_isapi.dll file, which handles requests to ASP.NET pages, cannot forward the request to the Asp.dll file, which handles requests to ASP pages.

Your haldler is creating problem,

try this:
This is caused by a custom HTTP Handler being added by another application that is most likely being run in the root of your web site.  To resolve the problem, modify the web.config file.  After  add:

```
<httpHandlers>
<clear />
<add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" /> 
</httpHandlers>
```